# how to set a Gtk RadioMenuItem as 'selected' without activating it

Tags: python, gtk

I have a menu with a few RadioMenuItems.

After the user selects an option, my program reloads the menu and therefore also resets the pointer to the selected item.

I need to programmatically set it back but without activating the function connected to it. `RadioMenuItem.set_active(True)` will activate the function. In fact, it seems that my function is called even when I do not call `set_active`, even just when the menu is drawn.

How do?

Comment: I usually do not program in python, but have you tried using handler IDs and object.disconnect(handler_id) as stated in http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-AdvancedEventAndSignalHandling.html ?

Comment: This very much looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why are you even "reloading" (whatever that means) the menu in such a way that it resets/destroys the widgets inside of it? I can't shake the feeling that you're doing something wrong here.

Comment: I'm updating the menu items with new data, just calling set_label() on them. This seems to trigger the 'activation'

Comment: @bluppfisk If that's true you should probably report it as a bug.

Comment: maybe I should. I'm not so sure if I understand what is going on or what is supposed to go on. However, I've found the solution. The signal I should connect is 'toggled', and then check if the widget's get_active() function returns True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `active` was the wrong signal to connect to a RadioMenuItem, even though it works perfectly fine for a regular MenuItem.

Instead, connecting the `toggled` signal, and then checking in the callback function whether the widget's `get_active()` function returns True, results in the desired behaviour.